# Quartz Display Services replacement for deprecated function CGWaitForScreenRefreshRects

Tags: quartz-graphics, screensharing

The method CGWaitForScreenRefreshRects is deprecated in  Mac OS X v10.8.
The alternative method mentioned in class reference(CGRegisterScreenRefreshCallback) is also deprecated.

What should I use to get the screen updates in 10.8?

Answer (score 0):

Look at CGDisplayStream.h. It is [new set of APIs](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/#releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_8/ApplicationServices.html) added to 10.8. Their is rare documentation on it though.